# SQL query to find data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table A1 and A2.
Table A1 has column shift index, date and amount and A2 table have column shift-index, name, and age.

1.How do find data with shift-index for that month.If I select shift-index 6,the data prior to 6 should populate.
The shift-index represents the date

[image: data]

Comment: seems great. What's stopping you?

Comment: looking for solution..How to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
where datecol >= dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date) and
      datecol < cast(getdate() as date)
```

This will return all rows where the date is between the first of the current month and yesterday.  On the first of the month, it returns no rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this

```
select * from YourTable
where YourDateColumn between 
                     DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and getDate() - 1
```

Just replace `getDate()` with your date value and give it a go